# How can I get total count of all children and children of children and other grand children in a generic JSON

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have a JSON file in which I have to validate the number of all of its nodes and sub-nodes. However, I can't find a generic way to get those counts

Here is how the JSON file looks

```json
{
  "total": 100,
  "offset": 0,
  "sources_used": [
    {
      "source": "mysource",
      "source_last_updated": "2018-10-24T16:16:10.698+00:00",
      "last_imported": "2019-01-17T22:13:03.861+00:00",
      "import_rate": ""
    }
  ],
  "search_performed_at": "2019-01-17T22:39:01.034+00:00",
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "label": "label1",
      "type": [
        "Countries"
      ],
      "sub_class_of": [

      ],
      ...............................
```

I do have to make sure that the `total` value up top corresponds to a number of nodes/children of the `results` element

I am able to successfully parse JSON file into .NET JSON Object

```cs
string contents = File.ReadAllText("jsonfile.json");
var jsonobject = JObject.Parse(contents);
```

Now the question is, how can I get all children/all elements of the `results` element so that I could validate it against a `total` element

Comment: `(jsonobject["results"] as JArray).Count`

Comment: What do the classes look like?  I would use Json Serializer to get classes to make it easier to get objects rather than use an anonymous object.  SEe : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data

Comment: Is that "Total" - Count a thing from an API that you have to obey? I really cannot think of any useful application of such a count in the context of JSON.

Comment: Yes, "Total" comes from API

Comment: @peinearydevelopment thank you sir, your solution was perfect

Answer (score 0):

`JObject.Parse` parses the text into a generic `object`, which doesn't tell much about the structure of the imported JSON.

If, instead, you create a class that closely represents your JSON Content (via an online tool like http://json2csharp.com/, for instance), you could run `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourJsonString)`.

`RootObject` would then contain a `Results` property of a `List<T>` type, against which you could execute a `Count`.

Comment: As far as I understand the question, OP would need a "deepCount", though. If an element of the Reselts-List has Children, he wants them to be counted, too. And their children down to the leaf nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Per advice from @peinearydevelopment this solution works best

```
var count = (taxonomy.JSONStructure["results"] as JArray).Count();
```